# HOW TO ADD HEADER AND FOOTER AT THE OF THE CODE TO GET THE REQUIRED O/P

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, header, utl-file

Write a procedure to genearte a report of all employee with managers name details with | (pipe delimiter) in unix development server /tmp path.

**Examp**le:**
Emp ID|Emp Name|Manager Name|Sal|Dept No|Location   -------header**
7369|SMITH|FORD|800|20|DALLAS

**Total Record|1                                      ------Trailer**

```
f_handle2  utl_file.file_type;
begin
f_handle2 := utl_file.fopen(
                'TESTING_DIR'     -- File location
              , 'EMP_DET_WITH_MANA_NAME2' -- File name
              , 'w'); -- Open mode: w = write. 
for i in (select empno,ename,manager_name,sal,deptno,loc,count(empno) from t77)
loop
utl_file.putf(f_handle2,i.empno||'|'||i.ename||'|'||i.manager_name||'|'||i.sal||'|'||i.deptno||'"'||i.loc);
UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(f_handle2);
end loop;
utl_file.fclose(f_handle2);
exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
raise;
end;
```

Comment: What is the problem with adding the header before the loop and the footer after it, using `utl_file.putf(header/footer text)`?

Comment: By the way, `sqlcode` is already part of `sqlerrm` so there's no value in duplicating it, and `dbms_output.put_line` is really for debug messages.